# SQL Sub query with Grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT customer_email, count(*) AS Order_Count,

MAX(created_at) as Last_Order_Date, 
SUM(base_total_paid) AS Total_Lifetime_Sales, 
SUM(base_total_offline_refunded+base_total_online_refunded) AS Refund_Total, 

FROM mage_sales_order AS o

WHERE o.created_at > “2018-01-01” 

AND

value NOT IN (Select customer_email 
FROM mage_sales_order
WHERE WHERE o.created_at < “2018-10-01”)
```

Trying to remove orders that have been purchased in the last week, however gets stuck on the WHERE AND, And not sure! Thank you for any help!

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: You should explain what you want to select. Something like "I want to select all customers who placed orders this year, but not within the last seven days. Per customer I want to count how many orders they placed this year, sum up their paid and refund amounts and show the date the last order date was placed. It is even recommended you show some sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to remove email id who ordered < '2018-01-01' so it would be below query

```
SELECT customer_email, count(*) AS Order_Count,     
MAX(created_at) as Last_Order_Date, 
SUM(base_total_paid) AS Total_Lifetime_Sales, 
SUM(base_total_offline_refunded+base_total_online_refunded) AS Refund_Total     
FROM mage_sales_order AS o     
WHERE o.created_at > '2018-01-01' AND    
customer_email NOT IN (Select customer_email 
FROM mage_sales_order
WHERE  o.created_at < '2018-10-01'
)
group by customer_email
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `group by`.  The answer to your question is:

```
SELECT customer_email, count(*) AS Order_Count,
       MAX(created_at) as Last_Order_Date, 
       SUM(base_total_paid) AS Total_Lifetime_Sales, 
       SUM(base_total_offline_refunded+base_total_online_refunded) AS Refund_Total 
FROM mage_sales_order AS o
WHERE o.created_at < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 week'
GROUP BY customer_email;
```

If you want to filter *customers* who haven't made a recent order:

```
SELECT customer_email, count(*) AS Order_Count,
       MAX(created_at) as Last_Order_Date, 
       SUM(base_total_paid) AS Total_Lifetime_Sales, 
       SUM(base_total_offline_refunded+base_total_online_refunded) AS Refund_Total 
FROM mage_sales_order AS o
GROUP BY customer_email
HAVING MAX(o.created_at) < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 week'
```

Note that date/time functions differ by database, so the exact syntax might differ depending on what database you are using.